# array of numbers to integers

Tags: jquery, arrays, int

I know there might be an easy way but I can not get this to work. Basically I am striping the values from an Associative Array and just creating another array of those values. Then I need to use those numbers as the data value from my chart.js graph.

Here is what I need:

`data: [ 50,0,50,200 ]`

This works when I hard code the numbers for the `data`

Here is what I have that doesn't work:

```
var categoryData = <?php echo (json_encode($categories)) ?>;
var categoryGraph = [];

$.each(categoryData, function (key, data) {
     categoryGraph.push(data);
});

console.log( categoryGraph.join() );

////Then the data I do like this

data: [ categoryGraph.join() ],
```

Console displays : `50,0,50,200`

I assume that because `categoryGraph.join()` outputs a string when `data` is looking for ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array itself as the value for `data`:

```
data: categoryGraph,
```

Comment: That causes an error in chart.js `Cannot read property 'custom' of undefined`. I am not sure why that does work either but hard coding in that same thing console.log outputs does

Comment: Shoot I forgot to remove the` data [ ] `when I did that the first time. Dumb mistake.